# SSIS Custom Component: Create Variable

Tags: variables, ssis, custom-component

Is it possible to create a variable from a SSIS custom component? I've been able to read or write existing variables, but no creating it from code and then write to it.

I'll explain longer what I'm trying to accomplish. I'll always have a SSIS project with 2 packages. The first one will always call via execute package task the second one. This second one is generic and unmutable in every SSIS project. Then the first one needs a way to pass a small string saying the name of the client, and I'm trying to accomplish this via a variable "shared" from parent (first package) to child (send package)

In fact it's already working but in a way that in first package I have to create manually the variable. In first package I have a custom component that makes some things and I also want to create that variable and set it. Now you are thinking, what's the problem then? Well, the first package will always be programmed by our clients and I have to facilitate their work, this is the reason I don't want them to create the variable, I want this process to be transparent for them, this is the reason I want to create the variable in the custom component.

Comment: Help me understand what you're attempting to accomplish. You have a custom component that does X. As part of X'ing, a variables gets created and we assign to that variable? This where where I get lost

Comment: I'm pretty sure SSIS variables have to be created at design time.   You can't write a component that creates them at runtime, I don't think.

Comment: Why not store your variable in a control table in SQL server? This can then be referenced / updated by your SSIS.

Comment: 1 of 2: Thanks everybody for the replies. I'll explain longer what I'm trying to accomplish. I'll always have a SSIS project with 2 packages. The first one will always call via execute package task the second one. This second one is generic and unmutable in every SSIS project. Then the first one needs a way to pass a small string saying the name of the client, and I'm trying to accomplish this via a variable "shared" from parent (first package) to child (send package).

Comment: 2 of 2: In fact it's already working but in a way that in first package I have to create manually the variable. In first package I have a custom component that makes some things and I also want to create that variable and set it.  Now you are thinking, what's the problem then? Well, the first package will always be programmed by our clients and I have to facilitate their work, this is the reason I don't want them to create the variable, I want this process to be transparent for them, this is the reason I want to create the variable in the custom component.

Comment: I would use MiguelH's idea then, and use a table to hold the value instead of a variable.